# Recently Viewed Products via cookie in laravel 7 only saves 1 products at any one time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have tried the script I found here [[Laravel/PHP] How to Make a “Recently Viewed Posts” Widget](https://www.256kilobytes.com/content/show/3282/laravel-php-how-to-make-a-recently-viewed-posts-widget)

It seems to be working, but only saves a single product in the cookie as opposed to 5.

Below is the code I am currently using in my `productController`

```
        $num_to_store = 5;
        $minutes_to_store = 1;
        $current_page['id'] = $product_material->id;
        $current_page['title'] = $material_category->title.' '.$product_material->title;
        $current_page['url'] = $request->url();
        $recent = Cookie::get('recently_viewed');
        $recent = json_decode($recent, true);
        if($recent){
            foreach ($recent as $key => $val){
                if($val['url'] == $current_page['url']){
                    unset($recent[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        $recent[ time() ] = $current_page;

        if(sizeof($recent) > $num_to_store){
            $recent = array_slice($recent, sizeof($recent)-5, sizeof($recent), true);
        }

        Cookie::queue('recently_viewed_content', json_encode($recent), $minutes_to_store);
        $recently_viewed_content = json_decode(Cookie::get('recently_viewed_content'), TRUE)
```

And here is my code in the blade file:

```
            @if($recently_viewed_content)
            @php(krsort( $recently_viewed_content ))
            @foreach($recently_viewed_content as $rvc)
                {{ $rvc['title'] }}
                {{ $rvc['url'] }}
            @endforeach
            @endif
```

Not sure what is wrong with it.

I have also tried implementing similar logic from here [Ecommerce Recently Viewed Products](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ecommerce-recently-viewed-products)

but it did not work for me either.

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

It was a simple typo in `Cookie::get('recently_viewed');`. It should have been `Cookie::get('recently_viewed_content');`